# Saving and loading a mesh into a file

Tags: javascript, three.js

I have several screens on stage, and are slow to load. so I have the idea to put it in a file and then load the meshes and add them to the scene. how can I do this? I have seen examples with

```
"THREE.JSONLoader()"
```

but can not find something like that where you see how the mesh is saved in a file and then load the full mesh from file.
My meshes are very big about 9000 vertices per file.

Comment: Are you loading directly from OBJ or PLY or COLLADA etc? In the THREE tools subdirectory you will find some converters to binary and json formats which load much, much more quickly than those standard-but-slow formats.

Comment: forgiveness. I know nothing about that. you can tell me more I searched everywhere for a way to keep a mesh to a file.

Comment: Have you cloned the THREE.js repo to your local machine? If not, do so: https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/ and look inside the utils/convertors directory (which you can also see here: https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/tree/master/utils/converters )